# are there open source validation parsers for major SQL dialects (TSQL, Oracle, MySQL)? or at least precise specs for these dialects?

Tags: sql, validation, parsing, dialect

word on the street is that Perl is defined not by a spec but by whatever the current interpreter version happens to accept. Now, let's consider an SQL dialect like TSQL. Is there a published spec of it that would allow making a validator equivalent to the one inside SQL Server? Are there such validators already in existence as open source? And the same question for Oracle.

Ok, so for MySQL I am guessing that validator could be extracted directly from the MySQL codebase. Nevertheless, do they in fact publish the spec itself in case I wanted to make my own validator?

Comment: Huh. On the one hand I feel stupid for not having thought to ask this myself (is there an official, syntactically strict T-SQL ruleset published somewhere), on the other hand this question has only been viewed 35 times in 4 months :( - if there is one, it could possibly have helped me a lot in writing the parsing rules for my Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter library. As it is, I've been using the syntax overviews on individual clauses/statements/keywords in BOL.

Comment: (and sorry, my library concentrates on formatting-relevant constructs only. It detects certain types of syntax errors (unclosed parens, unclosed blocks, missing statements, etc), but it is absolutely not a strict validator)

Comment: We have experience building SQL2012 and PLSQL 10g/11g parsers. In the first case, the standard is huge and building a validator is hard because of the sheer size of the thing... and of course, nobody implements it exactly, so the question is what does that buy you? Not much. PL/SQL is extended SQL + PL/SQL procedural language on top. There are online reference docs, but they aren't accurate and you have to validate your parsers against code encountered in the wild, which we have done. How accurate are these? We don't get a lot of complaints now, but there's always that possible surprise.

Comment: .... I suspect TSQL is like PL/SQL: "sort of" documented.

Comment: (Goofed: meant to say SQL2011).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an idea of what to do for MySQL. I can't really say much about Oracle apart from that it mostly implements ANSI SQL and the PL/SQL procedural language extensions to SQL can mostly be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/nav/sql_keywords.htm?remark=homepage) for Oracle 9i.

For SQL Server:

[Microsoft Books On Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177563%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) (BOL) is the official reference spec. There are different pages for different versions of SQL Server, however.
There are a few projects relating to this.
http://www.sqlparser.com/ - This has .NET, Java, COM and VCL versions for Oracle, DB2, Mysql and SQL Server / Sybase (T-SQL). Quite reasonably priced too.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1136/SharpHSQL-An-SQL-engine-written-in-C (c#)

http://antlr.org/ - This looks like a good bet.

I often use this site for formatting of SQL but it also does some validation although it's fairly crude:
http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

This is a similar site:
http://www.tsqltidy.com/

I would suggest that writing a validator for SQL even in just one of its variations is a massive undertaking. You could look at the various ISO/IEC standards for ANSI SQL. ANSI SQL-92 is very widely implemented, but there is a SQL:2008 standard as well. 
You'd have to pay for the documentation for those standards though and they aren't cheap.

Good luck.